# How to use the triangle inequality to get $d(x_k,y)\ge d(x,y)-d(x_k,x)$ (Prove limit of a sequence is unique)

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, inequality, convergence-divergence, proof-writing

[image]

Here, $d$ is the Euclidean distance:
[image]

And the triangle inequality in terms of $d$ is:

[image]

I have no idea how to come up with the $d(x_k,y)\ge d(x,y)-d(x_k,x)$ inequality.

What I've tried:

$\begin{align}
|x_k-y| &= & |x_k-x+x-y| \\
& \le & |x_k-x| + |x-y|&,& \text{ Triangle inequality} \\
\end{align}$

Therefore,
$d(x_k,y)\le d(x_k,x) + d(x,y)$

It does not look like I am anywhere near the required inequality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the triangle inequality, $d(x,y)\leq d(x,x_k)+d(x_k,y)$. So substracting $ d(x,x_k)$ on both sides, we get $d(x,y)-d(x,x_k)\leq d(x_k,y)$.